# Integrando projetos C# com VB

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, asp-net-core

Preciso criar um projeto C# que utilize uma DLL que foi escrita em VB.NET.

Adicionei a dependência, importei a biblioteca e utilizei o método. Porém, na hora da execução quando vou consumir um método que faz acesso à base de dados (e funciona normalmente nos projetos em VB.NET) recebo o seguinte erro:

> **System.IO.FileNotFoundException**: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado

Mesmo o projeto C# tendo a referência `System.Data.SqlClient` instalada via Nuget.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quantos projetos (csproj ou vbproj) tem a solução?

Comment: Bom é sabido que isso que você quer fazer funciona, o problema ai talvez seja a compatibilidade de versão e até falta de alguma referencia no projeto que vai utilizar. É um problema complicado para gente verificar.

Comment: @LINQ tem 6 projetos dentro desta solution.

Comment: Você referenciou a biblioteca também no projeto principal (o que é executado)?

Comment: @LINQ No projeto que está marcado como "Start up"? Sim, no caso é o que está no print. Se uso a dll em um outro projeto VB.net funciona normal, mas criei este projeto do Asp.net Core, adicionei a referencia via Nuget, e adicionei a referência à DLL (desenvolvida em vb) mas é como se as referências entre eles fossem diferentes... Tentei colocar a mesma referência da DLL no projeto C# mas não deixa dá mensagem de "Referência inválida ou não suportada".

Comment: Só pra tentar entender: a biblioteca é feita em .NET Framework e você tá tentando referenciar em um projeto .NET Core?

Comment: Sim.... sem chance? Nem importando as referências utilizadas?